# TextView null error despite text already declared

Tags: android, xml, string, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to show an array of `Strings` in my `RecyclerView`, but I get a null-related error even tho. I've scanned through the code but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. During deployment, the logcat returns this error:

> txtTitle must not be null

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private val ITEMTYPE = 100
    private val HEADERTYPE = 101
    private val INFOTYPE = 102

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false)
    }

    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var dataTitle: ArrayList<CharSequence>
    private lateinit var dataRating: ArrayList<String>
    private lateinit var dataDescription: ArrayList<String>
    private lateinit var mAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder>

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view

        mRecyclerView = v!!.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview)

        // set the linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

        // SpannableStrings
        // dynamically change SpannableString colour using defined attribute
        val attrS = intArrayOf(R.attr.spannablestringtextColor)
        val ta = activity!!.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrS)
        val colorSS = ta.getColor(0, Color.BLACK) //Color.BLACK - default value (colour will change automatically depending on chosen theme)
        ta.recycle()


        // SpannableString (start)
        val ssb1 = SpannableStringBuilder()

        val str1a = SpannableString(getString(R.string.placeholder1_placeholder2_placeholder3,
                " ", getString(R.string.product_a), " "))
        str1a.setSpan(BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, str1a.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        str1a.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.green)), 0, str1a.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        ssb1.append(str1a)

        val str1b = SpannableString(" " + getString(R.string.producta_feature))
        str1b.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(colorSS), 0, str1b.length, 0)
        ssb1.append(str1b)
        // SpannableString (end)


        // init data
        dataTitle = ArrayList()
        dataTitle.add(ssbA)
        dataTitle.add(getString(R.string.title_b))

        dataRating = ArrayList()
        dataRating.add(getString(R.string.rating_a))
        dataRating.add(getString(R.string.rating_b))

        dataDescription = ArrayList()
        dataDescription.add(getString(R.string.description_a))
        dataDescription.add(getString(R.string.description_b))


        // create the adapter
        mAdapter = createAdapter()

        // set the adapter
        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun createAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder> {
        return object : RecyclerView.Adapter<com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder>() {
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, type: Int): com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder {
                return when (type) {
                    HEADERTYPE -> com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.rv_header, parent))

                    INFOTYPE -> com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.rv_info, parent))

                    ITEMTYPE -> com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.rv_item, parent))

                    else -> com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.rv_item, parent))
                }
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                val rlProductInformation = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.rl_product_information)

                when (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    HEADERTYPE -> {
                        val buyButton = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buy_product)
                        buyButton.setText(R.string.buy)
                    }
                    INTROTYPE -> {
                        val tvIntroA = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_product_intro_A)

                        val tvIntroB = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_product_intro_B)
                    }
                    ITEMTYPE -> {
                        val itemA = dataTitle[position]
                        val itemB = dataRating[position]
                        val itemC = dataDescription[position]

                        viewHolder.tvTitle.text = itemA
                        viewHolder.tvSubtitle.text = itemB
                        viewHolder.tvDescription.text = itemC
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return dataTitle.size + 2
            }

            override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
                return when (position) {
                    0 -> HEADERTYPE
                    else -> ITEMTYPE
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun inflateHelper(resId: Int, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(resId, parent, false)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    internal class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_title) as TextView
        var tvSubtitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_rating) as TextView
        var tvDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_description) as TextView

        init {
            tvTitle; tvSubtitle; tvDescription
        }
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_recyclerView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_recyclerview"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarSize="3dp">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**RecyclerView item XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentPadding="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_cv_product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cv_product_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_product_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_product_information"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_product_new"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/board"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cv_product_title"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_product_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cv_product_title"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_product_new" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_product_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_product_rating" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put the RecyclerView initialization code in onViewCreated. The code is hard to read, but the error says that tv_product_title is nit defined in the respective layout xml for the item.

Comment: Do you mean all the code related to the RecyclerView?

Comment: Yes, then you have the view in method parameter list. But the main issue that the TextView is not found. Maybe you have several files for different API levels. Or you misspelled the id..

Comment: Can you add xml here?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's androidx. I can't spot your issue but it's suspicious why you have same id in card View and linear layout "@+id/cv_product". Another general comment you don't need find view by id in Kotlin. Typically when you have different view types and xmls, use different viewholders for them. The TextView should be inflated in ViewHolder class, not in onBindViewHolder. The way you do it breaks all the purpose of recyclerview when you need to save memory.

Comment: I fixed the duplicate id issue. Unfortunately I've not seen a Kotlin tutorial to inflate a TextView in ViewHolder class. I'm always aiming to save memory.

Comment: In my code there is onCreateViewHolder. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: See for example this https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-different-layouts/

Comment: The findViewById happens in ViewHolder. There you define TextView as a variable/object. In OnBindViewHolder it is used to set text.

Comment: After implementing a view holder, I get this error: `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView` which then points to this line: `var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_title) as TextView`

Comment: in `onBindViewHolder` before using the holder you need to cast to the specific ViewHolder: `holder as AddButtonViewHolder` for example

Comment: I'm a bit confused because I used `viewHolder: com.companyname.appname.MyFragment.ViewHolder`, so would `viewHolder as MyViewHolder` go at the top of `onBindViewHolder`?